# Modulo operator in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

From the "Programing in Objective C" (Kochan):

Program 5.8 prompts the user to enter a number and then proceeds to display the digits
from that number from the rightmost to leftmost digit.

```
// Program to reverse the digits of a number
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])

{
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int number, right_digit;

NSLog (@"Enter your number.");
scanf ("%i", &number);

while ( number != 0 ) {
right_digit = number % 10;
NSLog (@"%i", right_digit);
number /= 10;
}

[pool drain];
return 0;
}
```

My question is: what happening when user types in single digit number- 1 to 9 ? I couldn't find any material about such case. 
After compilation the program just proceed with returning that single digit. Why is that? 
I was trying to come up with code for this task and spend literally 2 hours, trying to incorporate loops and decision making for this " if number is single digit" problem. And the solution was so ignorant!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The modulo operator gives you the remainder after a division. If yo have 8 % 10 the result is 8 because 8 / 10 is 0 with a remainder of 8. You get the same result if you have 38 % 10, 38 / 10 is 3 with a remainder of 8.

edit:
Modulo is what you normally learned as the first division in elemantary school. It is funny that the most children have no problem with modulo but when they learned that 8 / 10 is 0.8 they have problems understanding modulo.

Comment: @Mr_Vlasov If this answers your question, you may want to accept it (by clicking the check mark outline next to it) to let others know that you are no longer looking for an improved answer, and to earn a brand-new badge on Stack Overflow.

Comment: plus 1 for the elementary school