# Checking to see if a number is divisible

Tags: objective-c, math, division

I want to check if a number is divisible by 6 and if not, I need to increase it until it becomes divisible.

Comment: Use the `%` modulus operator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293757/modulo-operator-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1):

Use the modulus operator. This operator returns the remainder of the division operation. Check if this is 0 to check if it divides perfectly.

```
if (i % 6 == 0) {
    // ...
}
```